# Multidomain - Second Domain - blank page?

Tags: multistore, ce-1.8.1.0

There are already a lot of posts to Multidomain, but since 1.8.1 something is wrong.
Installation: Magento CE 1.8.1 (fresh install 1.8 and update to 1.8.1)
Webserver: vHost on CentOS and Plesk v11.5.30

The Problem:
If I set the second website as "default store" the base domain shows a blank page only.
If I put the first website back as "default store, it is showing up the base website correctly.

Is there something missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure your websites work perfectly, you need to do mainly three things

1. Go to `system > manage store`. Click on the desired **website** and make it as **default**.
2. Go to `cms -> pages`. There you need to set a **Homepage** for your website and make sure that home page is **enabled**.
3. Go to `system -> configuration`. Change current `configuration scope` to your site's **store-view**(important). Under website tab, check whether all the informations are correct. Ensure the default pages are set correctly.
4. Now go to the `design` tab. There you need to specify your package and theme correctly.

You are done. In normal case your website will work perfectly

Comment: okay. Well now the Website works, when I have selected it as default. when is make the main domain default, and put the second on in the url of the browser, the main site appears.

Comment: okay!
Now i got it whith this addon in index.php:

    > switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    >     case 'seconddomain.eu':
    >     case 'www.seconddomain.eu':
    >         $mageRunCode = 'secd';
    >         $mageRunType = 'website';
    >     break; }
    > 
    > Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

Comment: glad to help you. happy codings